# having trouble with -notmatch and win32_process

Tags: powershell

here's my simple script. it cant seem to detect the text "GoogleChromePortable" or "FirefoxPortable" in my variable even though i can clearly see it when i output it. am i using NotMatch wrongly? i tried Notcontains as well and it doesnt seem to work. i'd like it to detect the string words so that i can launch the respective browser if its not running and to not launch it if its running.

```
$processlist=gwmi win32_process|select CommandLine|Select-String -Pattern chrome.exe,firefox.exe
write-output $processlist

If ($processlist -NotMatch "GoogleChromePortable") {
write-output "chrome not detected"
}

If ($processlist -NotMatch "\\FirefoxPortable\\") {
write-output "FirefoxPortable not detected"
}
If ($processlist -NotMatch "\\FirefoxPortable2\\") {
write-output "FirefoxPortable2 not detected"
}
If ($processlist -NotMatch "\\FirefoxPortable3\\") {
write-output "FirefoxPortable3 not detected"
}
```

here's the output:

```
@{CommandLine=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe -profile
C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile -no-remote}
@{CommandLine=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe -profile
C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\Data\profile -no-remote}
@{CommandLine=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe -profile
C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\Data\profile -no-remote}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.6.1254390342\729795331" -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 2640 -prefMapHandle 2632 -prefsLen 824
-prefMapSize 253217 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 - 2652 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.41.278929740\1196303478" -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 5856 -prefMapHandle 5852 -prefsLen 6711
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 5864
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.48.1094784849\526004255" -childID 7 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 5184 -prefMapHandle 5188 -prefsLen 919
-prefMapSize 253217 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 - 5256 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.55.1763573014\189394362" -childID 8 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 4288 -prefMapHandle 4424 -prefsLen 919
-prefMapSize 253217 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 - 5288 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.62.1413613940\766014382" -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 5832 -prefMapHandle 5852 -prefsLen 919
-prefMapSize 253217 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 - 5788 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.69.290952373\1345575100" -childID 10 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 7508 -prefMapHandle 5420 -prefsLen
6976 -prefMapSize 253217 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 - 7484 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="32280.55.500114489\1211004330" -childID 8 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 4240 -prefMapHandle 9840 -prefsLen
6952 -prefMapSize 251699 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\browser" - 32280 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.32280" 5268
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="32280.62.1737453149\249918842" -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 8372 -prefMapHandle 8376 -prefsLen
6952 -prefMapSize 251699 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\browser" - 32280 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.32280" 8420
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="32280.69.1676147553\1888616109" -childID 10 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 8264 -prefMapHandle 8260 -prefsLen
6952 -prefMapSize 251699 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\browser" - 32280 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.32280" 8272
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="32280.76.340122060\702497067" -childID 11 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 1248 -prefMapHandle 1616 -prefsLen
6952 -prefMapSize 251699 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\browser" - 32280 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.32280"
10140 tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="32280.83.1965015805\1717588162" -childID 12 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 7964 -prefMapHandle 7968 -prefsLen
6952 -prefMapSize 251699 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\browser" - 32280 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.32280" 8000
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.48.2064883553\847756466" -childID 7 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 3444 -prefMapHandle 5008 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 2408
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.55.576066106\326507723" -childID 8 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 5004 -prefMapHandle 6668 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 3644
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.62.613264775\17038639" -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 1576 -prefMapHandle 6356 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 6592
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.69.608041429\126312752" -childID 10 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 6804 -prefMapHandle 6500 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 6468
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.76.1817812537\835803251" -childID 11 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 3780 -prefMapHandle 6800 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 3604
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="708.83.2103839855\312605648" -childID 12 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 6792 -prefMapHandle 3364 -prefsLen 6758
-prefMapSize 252437 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir
"C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable2\App\firefox64\browser" - 708 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.708" 3656
tab}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\firefox.exe" -contentproc
--channel="13908.76.217218652\1589541068" -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -prefsHandle 10304 -prefMapHandle 10520
-prefsLen 7354 -prefMapSize 253217 -appdir "C:\Users\kuand\Documents\FirefoxPortable3\App\firefox64\browser" - 13908 -
3196 rdd}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile"
--disk-cache-dir="C:\Users\kuand\AppData\Local\Temp\GoogleChromePortable" }
@{CommandLine=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe --type=crashpad-handler
--user-data-dir=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile /prefetch:7
--monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler
--database=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile\Crashpad
--metrics-dir=C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
--annotation=channel= --annotation=plat=Win32 --annotation=prod=Chrome --annotation=ver=87.0.4280.66
--initial-client-data=0x2e4,0x2e8,0x2ec,0x248,0x2f0,0x5bad79f8,0x5bad7a08,0x5bad7a14}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=gpu-process
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --gpu-preferences=MAAAAAAAAADgAAAwAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAAAQAAAAgAAAAAAAAACgAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAQAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAEAAAAAAAAAABAAAABQAAABAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAYAAAA= --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1788 /prefetch:2}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=utility
--utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=network
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2000
/prefetch:8}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=utility
--utility-sub-type=storage.mojom.StorageService
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=utility
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2392
/prefetch:8}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile"
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=20 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=3024 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile"
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=19 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=3036 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile"
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=21 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=3156 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=6 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=3944 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=8 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4176 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=2688 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=10 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4212 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=11 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4308 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=12 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4380 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=13 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4204 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=14 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4100 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=15 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4580 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=16 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4608 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=17 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4644 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=renderer
--field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072 --lang=en-US
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile" --extension-process
--origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4
--enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=18 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=4776 /prefetch:1}
@{CommandLine="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" --type=utility
--utility-sub-type=audio.mojom.AudioService --field-trial-handle=1760,11890821617244175734,10769512138461397624,131072
--lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=audio --user-data-dir="C:\Users\kuand\Documents\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile"
--mojo-platform-channel-handle=6868 /prefetch:8}
chrome not detected
FirefoxPortable not detected
FirefoxPortable2 not detected
FirefoxPortable3 not detected
```

Comment: `$processlist.CommandLine -NotMatch "GoogleChromePortable"` can you try this?

Comment: is there a reason not to use something like >>> `Get-Process -Name 'firefox', 'foobar*', '*edge', 'chrome', 'BetterNotBeThere' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` <<< the resulting objects have a `.Path` property that will tell you where the file is located.

Comment: i actually did try : 
$processlist.CommandLine -NotMatch "GoogleChromePortable"
as well but didnt work. same results.

Comment: how would you make Get-Process to work? the following sample code results in nothing stored in $processlist even though the browsers are running. it works on the powershell command line but in a script it produces nothing.
$processlist=Get-Process -Name "firefox.exe","chrome.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
write-output $processlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `-NotMatch` on an array it is going to return all the items that do not match causing your condition to be true. So `If ($processlist -NotMatch "GoogleChromePortable")` will still return true because the firefox lines are returned.

Try with `-not` and `-match` instead

```
If (-not($processlist -Match 'GoogleChromePortable')) { Write-Host 'No Chrome' }
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i wanted! didnt realize -NotMatch meant show all non-matching items.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one ?

```
$processesToTrack = @("Chrome","firefox")

$processesToTrack | ForEach-Object {
    if ((get-process -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0 )
    {   Write-Output "$_ Not found"
    } 
}
```